# Some questions about the "append" function in Python

Tags: python

i've met a problem when using the append function of python.
if i code like this:

```
a={}
a[1]=[1]
b=copy(a)
b[1].append(2)
print (a)
```

the result will be:

```
{1: [1, 2]}
```

why? i think that using the copy function, the address of anything related to b will not influence a. but this append function is really strange! could anyone please tell me how this works? how could i append something without influencing the original address?
thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to make a deepcopy of a.

Answer (score 0):

`copy` only does a shallow copy. The list element `a[1]` is still copied by reference.

Comment: thx a lot. i changed the copy into deepcopy, and it works!